# Email Configration Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys I'm new to laravel. I'm trying to send a email but I can't understand how to configure it. I was looking at their email configuration and they were setting it up for mailgun etc. I don't want to set it up for any service. and if I have to is there any free service that can help me. Can somebody please explain to me how can I do that and I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Google searching your question returns more than 5 results **that are already on StackOverflow**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any free service, like [Gmail or Sendgrid](http://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5), for example.

Just fill settings in `.env` file to make it work:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yourEmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted`

Comment: I was ablt to solve the problem. The password was not correct. Can you please tell me If I want to receive email in my application how can do that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'recieve email in app'?

Comment: I mean to say that is there a way to not revieve email in gmail inbox but rather then receive them in my app

Comment: You can, but I don't think it's what you really want: http://www.sitepoint.com/piping-emails-laravel-application/

Comment: I'm  trying to scrap all the emails from my gmail account. If you have any good tutorial please tell me.Thanks